# How to pass phone number from TAPI to website?

Tags: javascript, php, tapi

I have a simple web application which has my pizza menu on and I can place orders, etc.

The webpage is built on php/mysql and using some javascript to provide quicker data for my customers (example further below)

Now the issue I'm faced with is I have to type phone numbers to find customers.

How can I go about getting the client side modem to detect the caller ID number and pass it to the webpage?

I appreciate that php can't help me here but I mention that to help understand the position I am in.

I have searched the internet for help to my problem but am left scratching my head, TAPI should help somewhere but as I am not familiar with C++ I'm left unsure where to start.

```
<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
      /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field     value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() ==     val.toUpperCase()) {
              /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "    </strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
              /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
              b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                  /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                  inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                  /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                  (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                      closeAllLists();
              });
              a.appendChild(b);
            }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being     submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
        removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
/*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
except the one passed as an argument:*/
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
          /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
          document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
              closeAllLists(e.target);
          });
        }

    var custs = [<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 


    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Telephone FROM customers";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($inc==0)
    {}
    else { echo ','; }
    echo '"' .$row["Telephone"]. '"';
    $inc+=1;
}}
$conn->close();
?>];
        </script>
<script>
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), custs);
</script>
```

My main question is do you guys know of anyway I could possible approach this that isn't going to take me days?

I know this is a bit out there so I really appreciate the time and thoughts of all to contribute! Thank you.

Comment: The question is pretty hard to understand, is the website public or are you the only user? Where is the modem in relation to the webserver? same machine or are you trying to remotely connect them ?

Comment: I have just 1 computer that can access the site, its not for the public. The modem is built into the client windows PC. And the webserver is remotely hosted. Thanks

Comment: you'd need some kind of tapi/network interface on the client which makes reqests to the server. I'd probably suggest trying something in node js or java as the barrier to entry is lower than c++. you might even find it easier to connect directly to the modem over RS232. Hayes AT commands are pretty easy to learn. I don't see any reason why you couldn't do the server side stuff with php. You could parse requests from the interface into a database via php and then read them back out with php when the request is made from the webpage

Comment: Just an observation but I'd recommend refining your existing code first. its very verbose. you may consider using an mvc like vue or angular. also there is no need to loop through an sql result set to produce a javascript array. see [php's json_encode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)